# Font embedded in main jasperreport but not in subreport when exporting to PDF

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, subreport, export-to-pdf

When previewing my report in jasper studio everything looks fine, both mainreport and subreports use the correct font.

Whenever I export the report to pdf it only displays the correct font in my main report and my header subreport. The footer subreport is using  the standard font. The title in my footersubreport are also not displayed in bold. Not even in bold using the standard pdf font.

I added the font to jasper studio -> preferences -> font select all .ttf files and checked embed in pdf.

I also tried adding the `isPdfEmbedded="true` property, this only gives a deprecaded warning but does not change the output.

any thoughts?

Comment: Try exporting the sub report individually and see the fonts.

Comment: Just tried exporting the subreport individually it uses the wrong font and no bold text as shown in 'preview'.

Comment: Then correct fonts in sub report indivually ..try to make it similar to your main report

Comment: The problem is, they look exactly like my main report and whenever I preview the subreport it looks just fine. It's only as soon as I export it to pdf things go wrong. This is the only subreport it happens to.

Comment: Try any other format for export and verify results.

Comment: Good news, in Word it displays the report corretly. I just can't understand how one pdf can recognize the font in one subreport but not the other while they are in the same PDF and using the same font.

Comment: Try on some other system ;)

Comment: It does work on other systems I tried that before, I'll just reinstall jasper studio and see what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem; Here is what I did:

Backup your project somewhere safe.
Remove project from jasper.
Remove previously installed fonts (Window -> preferences -> Jasper Studio -> fonts)
Delete JasperSoft Studio 
Reinstall jasperSoftStudio 
open previously backed up project again in JasperSoft Studio 
 
Rebuild project 
Change textfields to a font that is always embeded in pfd (sans serif or somehitng)
 
Export report to PDF 
 
See if Bold text appears 
 
Change back to custom font and export again

This did the trick for me. Changing fonts before I reinstalled did not work, only after I reinstalled Jasper. Also dont forget to delete custom fonts before deleting JasperSoft Studio, for some reason they appeared again after the fresh installation and it did not work.